# unordered_map::insert vs operator []= function giving error

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am inserting records to an unordered map, which results in an error, below is the program:

```
#include<tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int> u1;
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the no. of times" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int no_items;
        cout << "Enter no of items" << endl;
        cin >> no_items;
        for (int j = 0; j<no_items; j++)
        {
            int key, val;
            cout << "key=";
            cin >> key;
            cout << endl << "val=";
            cin >> val;
            u1.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(key, val)); //Compiler error
                                                           //u1[key]=val; //This line is working instead of insert.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`u1.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(key,val));` gives error

> - cannot convert 'key' (type 'int') to type 'int&&'
> - no matching function for call to       'make_pair(int&, int&)'

Wondering how `operator []` for inserting records into `unordered_map` is working and `insert()` function not.

Comment: Have you tried writing `u1.insert(std::pair<int,int>(key,val));`?

Comment: got the answer, new to programming so didn't get it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The 2 arguments for `std::make_pair` are forwarding references `T&&`. Just let the compiler do the type deduction instead:

```
u1.insert(std::make_pair(key,val));
```

Comment: Since we are dealing with templates they are forwarding references not rvalue references.

Answer (score 1):

```
u1.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(key,val));
```

works if g++ is invoked without -std=c++11

but for c++11, we need to give as...

```
u1.insert(std::make_pair(key,val));
```

Because earlier versions of make_pair is

```
template <class T1,class T2>
  pair<T1,T2> make_pair (T1 x, T2 y)
  {
    return ( pair<T1,T2>(x,y) );
  }
```

but from c++11, the signature is

```
template <class T1, class T2>
pair<V1,V2> make_pair (T1&& x, T2&& y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would even recommend doing emplace - to save on creating a temporary. Check out this:

```
u1.emplace(key, val);
```